# How to determine the length of a CLOB (in bytes) using the AL32UTF character set in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, byte, clob, utf

Is there is a way to find out the number of bytes used by a particular field value (which may or may not be longer than 4000 characters) in an Oracle SQL query?

`dbms_lob.getLength()` returns the number of characters not bytes and I can't just do a straight multiplication since there are a variable number of bytes per character in this character set. Briefly wondered about using `dbms_lob.converttoblob()` but this appears to need PL/SQL and I need to do this directly in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I haven't received a satisfactory answer yet I'm currently resorting to using `dbms_lob.getlength()` to get the number of characters and then multiplying by 2. This is based on a comment here about the AL32UTF8 character set:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2133623

> Almost all characters require 2 bytes of storage with a handful of
>   special characters requiring 4 bytes of storage.

Haven't verified how true this is but the person sounded like they knew what they were talking about so am currently using it as a "best guess".

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle function `LENGTHB()` to get this result.
there is a way around convert CLOB to BLOB by using `DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB` and use `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH()`. this is will return no of bytes.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but unfortunately lengthb doesn't seem to work on CLOBs...

Comment: ... and fixing the typo in function name ;-)